# How to split a string sequence and convert each element to a double

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, double

I am stuck on a problem for my programming class. We need to separate the argument String at the commas to produce an array of Strings, then it needs to parse each individual String to get a double, storing these doubles in sequence. We are also given some test code, with input arguments like ("1,5").

Here is my current code

```
public class Sequence
{

private double[] sequence;

public Sequence(String s)
{ 
  String[] res = s.split(",");

  int length = res.length;

  double[] result = new double[length];

  for ( int i =0; i<length; i++) {

  result[i] = Double.parseDouble(res[i])

  }

 }
```

Im not sure where to go from here because when i test my code, it dosent give the expected result. What does it mean by store in sequence ?

Comment: you are storing the parsed result in local variable...

Comment: I think i got it to work, instead of creating the array result, i put     sequence = new double [length]; and changed result[i] in the for loop to sequence[i]

Answer (score 2):

I have updated my answer, this might be what you are looking for:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Four {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String string = "1,2,10,4,9";

        System.out.println(string);

        double[] ds = getDouble(string);

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(ds[i]);
        }

    }

    private static double[] getDouble(String string) {
        double[] _double;
        String[] _Strings = string.split(",");

        _double = new double[_Strings.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < _Strings.length; i++) {
            _double[i] = Double.parseDouble(_Strings[i]);
        }
        Arrays.sort(_double);
        return _double;
    }

}
```

out put [image]

Comment: It would be helpful for future readers if you comment through your code or try to explain a bit of what it does. The variable naming isn't helping it. :p

Comment: @Unihedro, Thanks for the edit, i will keep this in mind, I understand variable naming can be annoying when someone else is reading, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
public class Sequence {

    private double[] sequence;

    public void createSequence(int sequenceLength) {
        sequence = new double[sequenceLength];
    }

    public void addToSequence(int index, double value) {
        sequence[index] = value;
    }

    public double parseDouble(String s) {
        return Double.parseDouble(s);
    }

    public String[] splitString(String s) {
        return s.split(",");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(sequence);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "10.10,20.20,30.30";

        Sequence sequence = new Sequence();
        String[] splitted = sequence.splitString(str);
        sequence.createSequence(splitted.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
            double doubleValue = sequence.parseDouble(splitted[i]);
            sequence.addToSequence(i, doubleValue);
        }

        System.out.println(sequence);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change `private double[] sequence;` to `private Double[] sequence;`
 and use below code

```
public class Sequence {

    private Double[] sequence;

    public Sequence(String s) {
        String separated[] = s.replace(" ", "").split(",");
        ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String num : separated) {
            list.add(Double.parseDouble(num));
        }
        this.sequence = list.toArray(new Double[separated.length]);
    }

}
```